# How do i fix "error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a part of code to take the rotation of my player and add it to another object. It says "error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3"

I've tried looking on the internet but i don't think their solutions will work with my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletCreator : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector3 MyGameObjectPosition;
    public Vector3 MyGameObjectRotation;



    //drag prefab here in editor
    public Transform InstantiateMe;

    private void Start()
    {



    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        MyGameObjectPosition = GameObject.Find("L96_Sniper_Rifle").transform.position;
        MyGameObjectRotation = GameObject.Find("L96_Sniper_Rifle").transform.rotation;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            //you don't have to instantiate at the transform's positio nand rotation, swap these for what suits your needs
            var go = Instantiate(InstantiateMe, MyGameObjectPosition, transform.rotation);

        }
    }
}
```

It should set the object's rotation value to the same value as the player.

Comment: You should convert your public Vector3 MyGameObjectRotation; to Quaternion MyGameObjectRotation;

Answer (score 1):

On which line do you get the error? It's pretty self-explanatory. Vector3 (a three-dimensional vector) and Quaternion (a quaternion is a mathematical representation of rotation) are two different things and can't be assigned to one another.

If you want the XYZ representation of rotation (similar to what the editor shows), that's called "Euler angle". You can convert a quaternion to its Euler angle representation like this:

```
Quaternion q;
Vector3 v = q.eulerAngles;
```

And you can convert a vector3 containing Euler angles to the corresponding quaternion like this:

```
Vector3 v;
Quaternion q = Quaternion.euler(v);
```

Comment: Im sorry i dont understand. Where would i put these lines of code?

Comment: Mabey someone else could tell me where i put them? please.

Comment: Recommendation: learn programming before trying to make a game out of code you find lying around on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Just change this:

```
public Vector3 MyGameObjectRotation;
```

to this:

```
public Quaternion MyGameObjectRotation;
```

And the rest should work.

Answer (score 1):

This should be your script.

```
    public Vector3 MyGameObjectPosition;
public Quaternion MyGameObjectRotation;



//drag prefab here in editor
public Transform InstantiateMe;

private void Start()
{



}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    MyGameObjectPosition = GameObject.Find("L96_Sniper_Rifle").transform.position;
    MyGameObjectRotation = GameObject.Find("L96_Sniper_Rifle").transform.rotation;

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //you don't have to instantiate at the transform's positio nand rotation, swap these for what suits your needs
        var go = Instantiate(InstantiateMe, MyGameObjectPosition, transform.rotation);

    }
}
```